# How python check data from user input that not include number and special characters

Tags: python

how can find all the special characters for using to check the user input name? I don't mean only the special characters on the keyboard, but all the special characters in Office, as well as all other languages, etc. Is there a function in the library for this? (not isalpha or isalnum its not perfect)
Also, I want to find which characters as special or digits.
update: this is a simple of this problem, isalpha does not help me because users can input this (Siavashستیبیلانذس). isalpha does not recognize language.

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
    if name.isalpha():
      print("Great!")
    else:
      print('Please check spell and insert correct Name!')
print("Your name is:", name)
```

Comment: If there is a database I think You can check the input according to the field type you are going to use in the database

Comment: Probably you should use utf8mb4 as the field type charset for the user name field, there are a lot of people use emojs in their names

Comment: And haven’t got into any trouble by doingso so far

Comment: [`isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) should give "not number or special characters" ... can you give an example where that doesn't give the result you want? that will help us to understand the problem more precisely

Comment: @Anentropic add example as what I want

Comment: `"ستیبیلانذس".isalpha()` returns `True` for me. Do you mean you want to disallow non-Latin characters?

Comment: @Anentropic isalpha() don't recognize language so users can insert str like this: albertشسنتاشنب so and this function don't recognize this issue

Comment: what is wrong with `albertشسنتاشنب` ?  it is not clear what is the problem definition

Comment: @Anentropic with isalpha() users can write with any language and we don't receive correct data, see fahim-ferdos answer (it's good) but rzlvmp is better.

Comment: which characters are allowed? is a French name like `Frédéric` invalid?  what about `Jean-Paul`?  if only ASCII chars are allowed then @rzlvmp's answer seems correct

Comment: @Anentropic Yes, I think rzlvmp answer's is better solution. also thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like name should be only ASCII alphabet characters

This will satisfy desired conditions:

```py
def is_name_correct(s):
  # isascii - check if string consists only ascii characters
  # isalpha - check if string consists only alphabet characters 
  return s.isascii() and s.isalpha()

print("Siavashستیبیلانذس", is_name_correct("Siavashستیبیلانذس"))
print("123", is_name_correct("123"))
print("aBc", is_name_correct("aBc"))
print("a BBB", is_name_correct("a BBB"))
print("a!", is_name_correct("a!"))
```

output:

```
Siavashستیبیلانذس False
123 False
aBc True
a BBB False
a! False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a python version **under python 3.7**, `.isalpha()` won't work due to it getting added in the 3.7 update. In which case I recommend using my code

## Code

```py
def is_name_correct(s):
  s = str(s)
  alphabet = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
  return all(ord(c) < 128 for c in s) and all(x == True for x in [d in alphabet for d in s])

to_check = ["English","Français","русский"]
for i in to_check:
  print(i,":",is_name_correct(i))
```

## Output

```
English : True
Français : False
русский : False
```